# possible to sort vscode Search: Find in Files by date (modified on)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Suppose I do:

```
ctrl+shift+p
Search: Find in Files
<provide search term>
```

Can I sort the results by recent changes?

Note, all included files are also under version control, if that matters.

Comment: It's a shame this hasn't been answered yet, I have been wondering about this for quite some months and finally tried searching for it.  If you have a folder with many folders and files and want to find the most recent instance of a search term, that seems like it would be a common thing to want to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It isn't very accessible (not on the search side bar / panel) but there is a setting for this:

> Features > Search > Sort Order

And an option to set it to modified like this in JSON:

```
"search.sortOrder": "modified"
```

That is still shown grouped by file but at last shows the most recently modified result first.